# Running python script when button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

When I run this Tkinter application, and the submit button is clicked. What should happen is the combobox_window.py should run automatically, and a new Tkinter window should open. However, when do so I get the error:

> 'combobox_window.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I was using originally using Sublime Text to code, and had no problem with running thecombo_box.py file when the button was clicked. Today I have converted to PyCharm (easier to import libraries), so I am new to it.

Any suggestions?

file1.py

```
class Completion(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    def next_page():
        os.system('combobox_window.py')

    submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=next_page)
    submit_button.pack()
```

combobox_window.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class SelectionWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    combobox_values = ("Hello", "Goodbye")        
    combo = Combobox(state="readonly", values=combobox_values)
    combo.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SelectionWindow()
    app.title("Selection Stage")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you execute combobox_window.py on the command line i.e. without adding python infront? It looks like it is not executable (needs permissions and missing the #/bin/xxx/python and/or not in the correct location.

Comment: Rethink, to use `'combobox_window.py'` as [python_module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm) using `import`.